# how to get a total value of an variable in Jquery each

Tags: jquery

I try to get the total that is returned whith this each :

```
 $.each(resStats,function(key, value){
     var test = value.users_count_view;
     console.log(test);            
 });
```

the `console.log` return 6 and 2. How i can have directly the result : 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st: Define `total` before/outside the loop .. If not it'll overwritten each time

2nd: Use `+=` to add value to the total in the loop

3rd: You'll need to use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.

4th: console.log the `total` outside the loop to give you the total value without console.log each time

```
var total = 0;
$.each(resStats,function(key, value){
   total += parseInt(value.users_count_view);           
});
console.log(total);
```

The above code will output `8`

If you use `console.log(total);` inside the loop

```
var total = 0;
$.each(resStats,function(key, value){
   total += parseInt(value.users_count_view);
   console.log(total);            
});
```

The above code will output `6` then `8`

Comment: thanks for your answers. The console.log return  '062'

Comment: @aurelienpirra answer updated .. this is because your value returned as string so you need `parseInt()`

Comment: @ Mohamed-Yousef  Yes whith the parseint() its worked, Thanks for your help !

Comment: You're totally welcome @aurelienpirra .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: My two cents... Reason why the need of `parseInt()` is the value type. A trick is to `console.log(typeof(value));` For maths, you need it to be "integer" or "float". If that is "string", it will be concatenated as a string... Making the `062`.

Comment: @ Louys Patrice Bessette thanks for the explain, now is clear !